# Pyxb Instance of <element> has no bound element for start tag

Tags: python, xml, schema, pyxb

I used a schema file (.xsd) to generate python classes for generating xml-code.
I can use all generated calsses but get an error if i try to

```
print d.toxml("utf-8")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py", line 541, in toxml
    dom = self.toDOM(bds)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py", line 513, in toDOM
    raise pyxb.UnboundElementError(self)
pyxb.exceptions_.UnboundElementError: Instance of type visionDataPackage has no bound element for start tag
```

It turns out that the element_name attribute of the element is missing. So if I set in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyxb/binding/basis.py element_name:

```
    element_name="visionDataPackage"
    if (element_name is None) and (self._element() is not None):
        element_binding = self._element()
        element_name = element_binding.name()
        need_xsi_type = need_xsi_type or element_binding.typeDefinition()._RequireXSIType(type(self))
    if element_name is None:
        raise pyxb.UnboundElementError(self)
```

Everything works.
So what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Probably what you're doing is creating `d` using its type, rather than an element.  For example, if your schema has:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:complexType name="atype">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="entry" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:element name="anelt" type="atype"/>
</xs:schema>
```

and you were to do `d = atype()` then `d` would not be bound to any element.  If you instead used `d = anelt()`, then `d` would still be an instance of `atype`, but it would be bound to `anelt`.  It is that binding that tells PyXB what element tag to use when generating a DOM or text XML representation from the object.

That PyXB formerly assigned a default element tag inferred from the underlying type when the object was not bound to an element was a [long-standing bug](https://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/pyxb/ticket/203) discovered and fixed in PyXB 1.2.3.

See additional discussion on the [PyXB SF discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/pyxb/discussion/956708/thread/fe705025/).